# Linkedlist visualization using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, beginner, html5, canvas

I have written a simple linked list visualization program in JavaScript:

[image: Linked list diagram]

I am just a beginner in html5 canvas. I am pretty much satisfied with how it works, but I´d like to know if I made some things, that could have been done better.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
 

var Shape=Shape || {
 x:0,
 y:0,
 w:0,
 h:0,
 t:0,
 rects:[],
 create:function(){
  var obj=Object.create(this);
  return obj;
 },
 add:function(x,y,w,h,t){
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
  this.w=w;
  this.h=h;
  this.t=t;
  this.rects.push({x,y,w,h,t});
 },
 draw:function(context,text){
  for (var i in this.rects) {
        oRec = this.rects[i];
        context.fillStyle = 'red'
        context.fillRect(oRec.x, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);
      context.fillText(oRec.t, oRec.x,oRec.y);
        context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo(oRec.x+oRec.w/2,oRec.y+oRec.h/2);
       context.lineTo(oRec.x+100,oRec.y+12);
       context.stroke();
       context.closePath();
       if(i==this.rects.length){

       }
   

    }
 }

};
window.onload=function(){
   var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
   var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
   var h=canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
   var w=canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
   var node=Shape.create();
   node.add(10, 100, 25, 25,1)
   node.add(100,100, 25, 25,2)
   node.add(200,100, 25, 25,3)
   node.add(300,100, 25, 25,4)
   node.add(400,100, 25, 25,5)
   node.add(500,100, 25, 25,6)
   node.draw(ctx);
   
};


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have data (coordinates and labels for the nodes) and a way to draw that data.  There is no need to solve this with mutation.  That is, get rid of your `add` method.  Instead, just have a draw function that accepts an array of objects, and draws them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you using `Object.create` to instantiate your shape. You should know that operator `instanceof` only works with real javascript pseudoclasses (that is, if you even think you need pseudoclass for this), which look like this:

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.w = 0;
  this.h = 0;
  this.t = 0;
  this.rects = [];
}
Shape.prototype = {
  add:function(x,y,w,h,t) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.w=w;
    this.h=h;
    this.t=t;
    this.rects.push({x,y,w,h,t});
  },
  draw:function(context,text) {
    for (var i in this.rects) {
      oRec = this.rects[i];
      context.fillStyle = 'red'
      context.fillRect(oRec.x, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);
      context.fillText(oRec.t, oRec.x,oRec.y);
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(oRec.x+oRec.w/2,oRec.y+oRec.h/2);
      context.lineTo(oRec.x+100,oRec.y+12);
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
      if(i==this.rects.length){
        // wtf is this exactly?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's also one very important difference, which is that in your case **rects property is shared between all instances!**. [Here's a demonstration using your `Shape`.](https://jsfiddle.net/093nqzcf/1/) [Here is the same example with my code.](https://jsfiddle.net/fy0m8upe/1/)

Except for that, there's nothing much to say about the code. I'd be more interested how does it actually handle a linked list. Does it check for cycles? Does it show whether the list is circular or null-terminated?

Maybe just make the text black and put it one pixel up for readability. [It looks better.](https://jsfiddle.net/ufbhm6gs/1/)

```
      context.fillStyle = 'black';
      context.fillText(oRec.t, oRec.x,oRec.y-1);
```